# Pixel manipulation and canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, global, pixel

Is there a way in javascript to change the alpha channels of each pixel into being fully transparent (a=0) while coding for pixel manipulation (meaning that you can still change the transparency in some of the alpha channels as desired)?

Basically, what I'm doing is: given some data for a specific image, I manipulate the pixel array using an algorithm so that some pixels become fully transparent  unless they satisfy some certain condition. In the case of them satisfying the condition I want them to be fully opaque, aka alpha=1. However, because of a complication with the way the algorithm works, I need to have my data "reset"; meaning I want the pixel array to start off as having every alpha = 0. I can provide code if that helps in better understanding the scope of my question.

Thanks so much.

EDIT: I'm looking more for a method/one-line code. Would context.globalAlpha = 0 serve the purposes? Is there any pitfall I should be careful about?

EDIT2: This is my code. Does globalAlpha where I've put it do what I'm expecting it to do? I'm not sure how to use it...

`function getBoundary(imagedata){
    var imageData = new Array(imagedata.data.length); 
    imageData = imagedata.data;
    var w = imagedata.width; 
    var h = imagedata.height;

    var color1 = [];
    var colorRight = [];
    var colorDown = [];
    context.globalAlpha = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < 4*w*h; i +=4) {
        color1 = [imageData[i],imageData[i+1],imageData[i+2]];

        colorRight = [imageData[i+4],imageData[i+5],imageData[i+6]];
    colorDown = [imageData[4*w+i],imageData[4*w+i+1],imageData[4*w+i+2]];

        if(colorRight = [255,255,255]){    //if right is white
            if(color1 = [0,0,0]){
               imageData[i+3] = 255;
            }
            else{
                if(colorDown = [0,0,0]){
                    imageData[4*w+i+3] = 255; 
                }
            }
        }
        else{                             //colorRight = black
            if(color1 = [0,0,0]){
                if(colorDown = [255,255,255]){
                    imageData[i+3] = 255;
                }
            }
            else if(color1 = [255,255,255]){
                imageData[i+7] = 255;
                if(colorDown = [0,0,0]){
                    imageData[4*w+i+3] = 255;
                }
                else{
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("done");
    imagedata.data = imageData;
    return imagedata;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getImageData` and flip all the alpha elements to zero:

You can create a function that zeros the alpha of all pixels on the canvas like this:

```
function zeroAllAlpha(){

    var imageData=context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    var data=imageData.data;

    // set all alpha elements to zero (fully transparent);

    for(var i=3;i<data.length;i+=4){

        data[i]=0;

    }

    context.putImageData(imagedata,0,0);

}
```

And you can call the function with one line like this:

```
zeroAllAlpha();
```

Comment: I was wondering something less code. maybe a sentence, like a method or sth.

Comment: the code for algorithm itself takes much space :P but if there is no method, i guess i'll just code it up too.

Comment: Just wrap the code in a function and then you can call that function with one line of code.